# Batch File does not work after activating python virtual environment

Tags: python, batch-file

I stored the below in a batch file. But the file does not complete because of this line:

```
convert-to-exe\scripts\activate
```

How can I make it execute that command and continue executing the rest of the lines in the same window?

```
ECHO OFF
COLOR 0F
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv convert-to-exe
convert-to-exe\scripts\activate
pip install gspread
pip install openpyxl
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile "ZSCRIPT.py"
```

Comment: One of the most common [[tag:python]] [[tag:batch-file]] issues on this entire site. Please in future use the search facility at the top of the page, to find answers to your problem, before submitting a duplicate question. ```activate``` is a lazy and poor form of running a file, without its extension. If you take a look at its extension, you'll see that it is a batch file. If you want to run a batch file from another, and return to the original script with the same environment, you'll need to `CALL` that batch file. example: ```call convert-to-exe\scripts\activate.bat```.

Comment: apologies as i was finding various suggestions that werent working...:
1. using start 
2. using cmd /k
3. using cmd /d
4. using call
5. adding .bat to the end of the file name activate. That confused me more because there is a file called activate and a file called activate.bat ... so unsure of which one to use as well. Lastly using call worked - i also was getting messed up with some small typos.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what type of executable `convert-to-exe\scripts\activate` is, but given its location, it's presumably a script, so...

```
call convert-to-exe\scripts\activate
```

should solve your problem.